# Issue with date function in PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm working on weekly schedule report.

I'm generating week on the basis of current date. Refer following code.

```
<?php 
    $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); 
    $week = (int)date('W', $date); 
    $year = date('Y');

    for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
    {
        echo date('M dS, Y', strtotime($year."W".$week.$day));
    }
?>
```

This is working fine, but when I try to navigate between weeks, I'm facing issues. For week 9 I'm getting date 01-03-1970. It's not generating week dates for February.

Also tried with static date 03-02-2012 but getting same random date.

```
$week =9; //(int)date('W', $date);
```

In another Issue

```
echo date('N', strtotime('03-09-2012'));
```

above satement returning `1`. I'm not convinced with the result here.

Please let me know what should I do to over come with this or help me to find out way to get no of day of the week for given date.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to get me solution. I appreciate all your efforts. Answers so far were close but not exactly what I wanted. Special Thanks to @kdvy for pointing out issues in my code and resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to keep the solution as close to your current code as possible.

**For your 1970 issue:**

It appears that strtotime requires zero-leading week numbers to work correctly for those weeks under 10, otherwise it outputs to 1970, ignoring the year (this seems like a bug to me?). Though, support for weeks and day of week isn't in the official documentation for strtotime.

So I would replace

```
    $week = (int)date('W', $date);
```

with:

```
    $week = str_pad(date('W', $date),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Regarding the following code:**

```
    echo date('N', strtotime('03-09-2012'));
```

This is returning 1 (Monday) as strtotime is interpreting **03-09-2012** in the UK format of **d-m-Y** as opposed to the US format of m-d-Y. To avoid confusion you should use the ISO date format of **Y-m-d**. See [PHP manual on Date Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for more information.

So if you wanted 9th March 2012 you would write:

```
    echo date('N', strtotime('2012-03-09'));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly What i Wanted to know to overcome with this date issue. Thank you So Much.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which version of PHP you are running, but you should use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object, with [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval)

It's way better and more easier to use.

Comment: I'm Using Wamp Server - Apache Version : 2.2.21  PHP Version : 5.3.8

Comment: You are good to go! The least version of PHP should be 5.3.0, yours is higher (it's for http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. It's a function to return the calendar dates of the given year:

```
<?php

  /**
   * Get all the dates in the given year's calendar
   *
   * @param NULL|integer $year
   * @param string $format
   * @return array
   */
  function getCalendar($year = NULL, $format = 'Y-m-d')
  {

    // If the year is not set then use the current
    if (!isset($year))
    {
      $year = date('Y');
    }

    // Get the first day of the year
    $start = $year . '-01-01';

    // Iterate over an incremental day increase
    for ($d = 0; ; ++$d)
    {

      // Get the date
      $date = strtotime($start . " + $d day");

      // Return the current list of dates if the current date is for next year
      if ($date >= strtotime($year + 1 . '-01-01'))
      {
        return $dates;
      }

      // Get the week number
      $w = ceil(($d + 1) / 7);

      // Add the date to the array
      $dates[isset($dates[$w][7]) ? ++$w : $w][date('N', $date)] = date($format, $date);

    }

    // Return the dates array
    return $dates;

  }

  // Get the calendar for 2012
  echo '<pre>' . print_r(getCalendar(2012, 'M dS, Y'), true) . '</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [7] => Jan 01st, 2012
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jan 02nd, 2012
            [2] => Jan 03rd, 2012
            [3] => Jan 04th, 2012
            [4] => Jan 05th, 2012
            [5] => Jan 06th, 2012
            [6] => Jan 07th, 2012
            [7] => Jan 08th, 2012
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jan 09th, 2012
            [2] => Jan 10th, 2012
            [3] => Jan 11th, 2012
            [4] => Jan 12th, 2012
            [5] => Jan 13th, 2012
            [6] => Jan 14th, 2012
            [7] => Jan 15th, 2012
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jan 16th, 2012
            [2] => Jan 17th, 2012
            [3] => Jan 18th, 2012
            [4] => Jan 19th, 2012
            [5] => Jan 20th, 2012
            [6] => Jan 21st, 2012
            [7] => Jan 22nd, 2012
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jan 23rd, 2012
            [2] => Jan 24th, 2012
            [3] => Jan 25th, 2012
            [4] => Jan 26th, 2012
            [5] => Jan 27th, 2012
            [6] => Jan 28th, 2012
            [7] => Jan 29th, 2012
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jan 30th, 2012
            [2] => Jan 31st, 2012
            [3] => Feb 01st, 2012
            [4] => Feb 02nd, 2012
            [5] => Feb 03rd, 2012
            [6] => Feb 04th, 2012
            [7] => Feb 05th, 2012
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [1] => Feb 06th, 2012
            [2] => Feb 07th, 2012
            [3] => Feb 08th, 2012
            [4] => Feb 09th, 2012
            [5] => Feb 10th, 2012
            [6] => Feb 11th, 2012
            [7] => Feb 12th, 2012
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [1] => Feb 13th, 2012
            [2] => Feb 14th, 2012
            [3] => Feb 15th, 2012
            [4] => Feb 16th, 2012
            [5] => Feb 17th, 2012
            [6] => Feb 18th, 2012
            [7] => Feb 19th, 2012
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [1] => Feb 20th, 2012
            [2] => Feb 21st, 2012
            [3] => Feb 22nd, 2012
            [4] => Feb 23rd, 2012
            [5] => Feb 24th, 2012
            [6] => Feb 25th, 2012
            [7] => Feb 26th, 2012
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [1] => Feb 27th, 2012
            [2] => Feb 28th, 2012
            [3] => Feb 29th, 2012
            [4] => Mar 01st, 2012
            [5] => Mar 02nd, 2012
            [6] => Mar 03rd, 2012
            [7] => Mar 04th, 2012
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [1] => Mar 05th, 2012
            [2] => Mar 06th, 2012
            [3] => Mar 07th, 2012
            [4] => Mar 08th, 2012
            [5] => Mar 09th, 2012
            [6] => Mar 10th, 2012
            [7] => Mar 11th, 2012
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [1] => Mar 12th, 2012
            [2] => Mar 13th, 2012
            [3] => Mar 14th, 2012
            [4] => Mar 15th, 2012
            [5] => Mar 16th, 2012
            [6] => Mar 17th, 2012
            [7] => Mar 18th, 2012
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [1] => Mar 19th, 2012
            [2] => Mar 20th, 2012
            [3] => Mar 21st, 2012
            [4] => Mar 22nd, 2012
            [5] => Mar 23rd, 2012
            [6] => Mar 24th, 2012
            [7] => Mar 25th, 2012
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [1] => Mar 26th, 2012
            [2] => Mar 27th, 2012
            [3] => Mar 28th, 2012
            [4] => Mar 29th, 2012
            [5] => Mar 30th, 2012
            [6] => Mar 31st, 2012
            [7] => Apr 01st, 2012
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [1] => Apr 02nd, 2012
            [2] => Apr 03rd, 2012
            [3] => Apr 04th, 2012
            [4] => Apr 05th, 2012
            [5] => Apr 06th, 2012
            [6] => Apr 07th, 2012
            [7] => Apr 08th, 2012
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [1] => Apr 09th, 2012
            [2] => Apr 10th, 2012
            [3] => Apr 11th, 2012
            [4] => Apr 12th, 2012
            [5] => Apr 13th, 2012
            [6] => Apr 14th, 2012
            [7] => Apr 15th, 2012
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [1] => Apr 16th, 2012
            [2] => Apr 17th, 2012
            [3] => Apr 18th, 2012
            [4] => Apr 19th, 2012
            [5] => Apr 20th, 2012
            [6] => Apr 21st, 2012
            [7] => Apr 22nd, 2012
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [1] => Apr 23rd, 2012
            [2] => Apr 24th, 2012
            [3] => Apr 25th, 2012
            [4] => Apr 26th, 2012
            [5] => Apr 27th, 2012
            [6] => Apr 28th, 2012
            [7] => Apr 29th, 2012
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [1] => Apr 30th, 2012
            [2] => May 01st, 2012
            [3] => May 02nd, 2012
            [4] => May 03rd, 2012
            [5] => May 04th, 2012
            [6] => May 05th, 2012
            [7] => May 06th, 2012
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [1] => May 07th, 2012
            [2] => May 08th, 2012
            [3] => May 09th, 2012
            [4] => May 10th, 2012
            [5] => May 11th, 2012
            [6] => May 12th, 2012
            [7] => May 13th, 2012
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [1] => May 14th, 2012
            [2] => May 15th, 2012
            [3] => May 16th, 2012
            [4] => May 17th, 2012
            [5] => May 18th, 2012
            [6] => May 19th, 2012
            [7] => May 20th, 2012
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [1] => May 21st, 2012
            [2] => May 22nd, 2012
            [3] => May 23rd, 2012
            [4] => May 24th, 2012
            [5] => May 25th, 2012
            [6] => May 26th, 2012
            [7] => May 27th, 2012
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [1] => May 28th, 2012
            [2] => May 29th, 2012
            [3] => May 30th, 2012
            [4] => May 31st, 2012
            [5] => Jun 01st, 2012
            [6] => Jun 02nd, 2012
            [7] => Jun 03rd, 2012
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jun 04th, 2012
            [2] => Jun 05th, 2012
            [3] => Jun 06th, 2012
            [4] => Jun 07th, 2012
            [5] => Jun 08th, 2012
            [6] => Jun 09th, 2012
            [7] => Jun 10th, 2012
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jun 11th, 2012
            [2] => Jun 12th, 2012
            [3] => Jun 13th, 2012
            [4] => Jun 14th, 2012
            [5] => Jun 15th, 2012
            [6] => Jun 16th, 2012
            [7] => Jun 17th, 2012
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jun 18th, 2012
            [2] => Jun 19th, 2012
            [3] => Jun 20th, 2012
            [4] => Jun 21st, 2012
            [5] => Jun 22nd, 2012
            [6] => Jun 23rd, 2012
            [7] => Jun 24th, 2012
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jun 25th, 2012
            [2] => Jun 26th, 2012
            [3] => Jun 27th, 2012
            [4] => Jun 28th, 2012
            [5] => Jun 29th, 2012
            [6] => Jun 30th, 2012
            [7] => Jul 01st, 2012
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jul 02nd, 2012
            [2] => Jul 03rd, 2012
            [3] => Jul 04th, 2012
            [4] => Jul 05th, 2012
            [5] => Jul 06th, 2012
            [6] => Jul 07th, 2012
            [7] => Jul 08th, 2012
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jul 09th, 2012
            [2] => Jul 10th, 2012
            [3] => Jul 11th, 2012
            [4] => Jul 12th, 2012
            [5] => Jul 13th, 2012
            [6] => Jul 14th, 2012
            [7] => Jul 15th, 2012
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jul 16th, 2012
            [2] => Jul 17th, 2012
            [3] => Jul 18th, 2012
            [4] => Jul 19th, 2012
            [5] => Jul 20th, 2012
            [6] => Jul 21st, 2012
            [7] => Jul 22nd, 2012
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jul 23rd, 2012
            [2] => Jul 24th, 2012
            [3] => Jul 25th, 2012
            [4] => Jul 26th, 2012
            [5] => Jul 27th, 2012
            [6] => Jul 28th, 2012
            [7] => Jul 29th, 2012
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jul 30th, 2012
            [2] => Jul 31st, 2012
            [3] => Aug 01st, 2012
            [4] => Aug 02nd, 2012
            [5] => Aug 03rd, 2012
            [6] => Aug 04th, 2012
            [7] => Aug 05th, 2012
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [1] => Aug 06th, 2012
            [2] => Aug 07th, 2012
            [3] => Aug 08th, 2012
            [4] => Aug 09th, 2012
            [5] => Aug 10th, 2012
            [6] => Aug 11th, 2012
            [7] => Aug 12th, 2012
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [1] => Aug 13th, 2012
            [2] => Aug 14th, 2012
            [3] => Aug 15th, 2012
            [4] => Aug 16th, 2012
            [5] => Aug 17th, 2012
            [6] => Aug 18th, 2012
            [7] => Aug 19th, 2012
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [1] => Aug 20th, 2012
            [2] => Aug 21st, 2012
            [3] => Aug 22nd, 2012
            [4] => Aug 23rd, 2012
            [5] => Aug 24th, 2012
            [6] => Aug 25th, 2012
            [7] => Aug 26th, 2012
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [1] => Aug 27th, 2012
            [2] => Aug 28th, 2012
            [3] => Aug 29th, 2012
            [4] => Aug 30th, 2012
            [5] => Aug 31st, 2012
            [6] => Sep 01st, 2012
            [7] => Sep 02nd, 2012
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [1] => Sep 03rd, 2012
            [2] => Sep 04th, 2012
            [3] => Sep 05th, 2012
            [4] => Sep 06th, 2012
            [5] => Sep 07th, 2012
            [6] => Sep 08th, 2012
            [7] => Sep 09th, 2012
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [1] => Sep 10th, 2012
            [2] => Sep 11th, 2012
            [3] => Sep 12th, 2012
            [4] => Sep 13th, 2012
            [5] => Sep 14th, 2012
            [6] => Sep 15th, 2012
            [7] => Sep 16th, 2012
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [1] => Sep 17th, 2012
            [2] => Sep 18th, 2012
            [3] => Sep 19th, 2012
            [4] => Sep 20th, 2012
            [5] => Sep 21st, 2012
            [6] => Sep 22nd, 2012
            [7] => Sep 23rd, 2012
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [1] => Sep 24th, 2012
            [2] => Sep 25th, 2012
            [3] => Sep 26th, 2012
            [4] => Sep 27th, 2012
            [5] => Sep 28th, 2012
            [6] => Sep 29th, 2012
            [7] => Sep 30th, 2012
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [1] => Oct 01st, 2012
            [2] => Oct 02nd, 2012
            [3] => Oct 03rd, 2012
            [4] => Oct 04th, 2012
            [5] => Oct 05th, 2012
            [6] => Oct 06th, 2012
            [7] => Oct 07th, 2012
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [1] => Oct 08th, 2012
            [2] => Oct 09th, 2012
            [3] => Oct 10th, 2012
            [4] => Oct 11th, 2012
            [5] => Oct 12th, 2012
            [6] => Oct 13th, 2012
            [7] => Oct 14th, 2012
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [1] => Oct 15th, 2012
            [2] => Oct 16th, 2012
            [3] => Oct 17th, 2012
            [4] => Oct 18th, 2012
            [5] => Oct 19th, 2012
            [6] => Oct 20th, 2012
            [7] => Oct 21st, 2012
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [1] => Oct 22nd, 2012
            [2] => Oct 23rd, 2012
            [3] => Oct 24th, 2012
            [4] => Oct 25th, 2012
            [5] => Oct 26th, 2012
            [6] => Oct 27th, 2012
            [7] => Oct 28th, 2012
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [1] => Oct 29th, 2012
            [2] => Oct 30th, 2012
            [3] => Oct 31st, 2012
            [4] => Nov 01st, 2012
            [5] => Nov 02nd, 2012
            [6] => Nov 03rd, 2012
            [7] => Nov 04th, 2012
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [1] => Nov 05th, 2012
            [2] => Nov 06th, 2012
            [3] => Nov 07th, 2012
            [4] => Nov 08th, 2012
            [5] => Nov 09th, 2012
            [6] => Nov 10th, 2012
            [7] => Nov 11th, 2012
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [1] => Nov 12th, 2012
            [2] => Nov 13th, 2012
            [3] => Nov 14th, 2012
            [4] => Nov 15th, 2012
            [5] => Nov 16th, 2012
            [6] => Nov 17th, 2012
            [7] => Nov 18th, 2012
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [1] => Nov 19th, 2012
            [2] => Nov 20th, 2012
            [3] => Nov 21st, 2012
            [4] => Nov 22nd, 2012
            [5] => Nov 23rd, 2012
            [6] => Nov 24th, 2012
            [7] => Nov 25th, 2012
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [1] => Nov 26th, 2012
            [2] => Nov 27th, 2012
            [3] => Nov 28th, 2012
            [4] => Nov 29th, 2012
            [5] => Nov 30th, 2012
            [6] => Dec 01st, 2012
            [7] => Dec 02nd, 2012
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [1] => Dec 03rd, 2012
            [2] => Dec 04th, 2012
            [3] => Dec 05th, 2012
            [4] => Dec 06th, 2012
            [5] => Dec 07th, 2012
            [6] => Dec 08th, 2012
            [7] => Dec 09th, 2012
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [1] => Dec 10th, 2012
            [2] => Dec 11th, 2012
            [3] => Dec 12th, 2012
            [4] => Dec 13th, 2012
            [5] => Dec 14th, 2012
            [6] => Dec 15th, 2012
            [7] => Dec 16th, 2012
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [1] => Dec 17th, 2012
            [2] => Dec 18th, 2012
            [3] => Dec 19th, 2012
            [4] => Dec 20th, 2012
            [5] => Dec 21st, 2012
            [6] => Dec 22nd, 2012
            [7] => Dec 23rd, 2012
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [1] => Dec 24th, 2012
            [2] => Dec 25th, 2012
            [3] => Dec 26th, 2012
            [4] => Dec 27th, 2012
            [5] => Dec 28th, 2012
            [6] => Dec 29th, 2012
            [7] => Dec 30th, 2012
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [1] => Dec 31st, 2012
        )

)
```

As you can see, it's in the form `$array[$week_number][$day_number]` (where a `$day_number` of 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday) and the `$week_number` will be up to 53 or 54 (depending on the year).

You can then get a specific week's dates using:

```
$calendar = getCalendar();

$calendar[9];

// Or if you have PHP 5.4.0

getCalendar()[9];
```

I've intentionally not included days from the previous or next years at the beginning and the end.

Answer (score 1):

Following code

```
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 2012);

$offset = date('N', $ts);

for ($i = 1 - $offset, $j = 0; $j++ < 7; $i++) {
    echo date('r', $ts + $i * 3600 * 24) . "\n";
}
```

outputs days of the week the specified day belongs to:

```
Apr 02nd, 2012
Apr 03rd, 2012
Apr 04th, 2012
Apr 05th, 2012
Apr 06th, 2012
Apr 07th, 2012
Apr 08th, 2012
```

I hope this is what you were after.

As for issue with strtotime check if the date returned is really the date your were after by doing

```
echo date('r', strtotime('03-09-2012'));
```

It is safer to pass date to strtotime as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

using the DateTime class  (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0):

```
    $date = date_create();

    for($d=1; $d<=7; $d++){

        echo $date->format('M dS, Y')."<br />";         
        $date->modify('+1 day');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works fine for me:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['diffweek'])){
  $diffweek=$_GET['diffweek'];
}else{
  $diffweek=0;}

$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); 
$week = date('W', $date+$diffweek*604800); 
$year = date('Y');

for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
  {
  echo date('M dS, Y', strtotime($year."W".$week.$day));
  echo '<hr>';
  }

echo '<a href="?diffweek='.($diffweek-4).'">4 weeks back</a><br>';
echo '<a href="?diffweek='.($diffweek-1).'">prew. week</a><br>';
echo '<a href="?diffweek=0">this week</a><br>';
echo '<a href="?diffweek='.($diffweek+1).'">next week</a><br>';
echo '<a href="?diffweek='.($diffweek+4).'">4 week later</a><br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think weeks in strtotime is supposed to be formatted like yeer-week-weekday i.e. 2012-W14-3.

```
for ($day=1; $day<=7; $day++) {
    echo date('M dS, Y', strtotime(date('Y') ."-W". date('W') .'-'. $day));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. The 'today' in the first line can be changed to whatever date you want to test it for.

```
<?php 
$today = strtotime('today');
$startWeek = strtotime(date('o-\\WW', $today));
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $startWeek), date('d', $startWeek), date('Y', $startWeek)); 
$week = (int)date('W', $date); 
$year = date('Y', $date);

for($day=0; $day < 7; $day++)
{
    echo date('M dS, Y', $today + ($day * 24 * 60 * 60)), "\n";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.